# Insert a max value from a column into the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, max

How to insert into Column1 a new number that is a maximum of values already in Column1?

`$qry = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES('2')";`// it will insert '2'.

But, I want to insert a maximum number from Column1.

Comment: What version of sql are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you need.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Column1)
SELECT MAX(Column1)
FROM Table1
```

Comment: can i use it along with other values ??

Comment: @SoliQuiD, I'm not sure I fully understand your question - if you have a second column, you should be able to add it: `SELECT MAX(Column1), 'secondValue'`.  You may need to set up a group by in the SELECT query to handle the aggregates, I'm not familiar enough with the ins and outs of MySQL to say for sure at this point.  If you are having issues with this after testing, creating a separate question with your issue should get you a concrete answer.